# Why PouchDb put(doc) method is editing my parameter?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I have a custom object like this:

```
function BlobModel(id){
    this._id = id;
    this._rev = null;
    this.filename = '';
    this.index = '';
    this.data = '';
}
```

If I put it in my pouch database it works fine, but I have a strange issue, if I do this:

```
var myDoc = new BlobModel('myId');

db.put(myDoc).then(function(){
    console.log(myDoc);
})
```

console.log result:
[image]
Why I got **_rev value** and **_rev_tree property** added to my `myDoc` parameter, it should be added only in the document inside the db. Why it's not same behavior as a native object ? How to fix it ? The only way I see is to clone my object before putting it, but it's weird on heavy objects.

If I do it with a native object, it won't be modified:

```
var myDoc = {
    _id: 'myId',
    _rev: null,
    filename: '',
    index: '',
    data: ''
}

db.put(myDoc).then(function(){
    console.log(myDoc);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PouchDB expects you to insert plain JavaScript objects as your documents. If you try to insert custom classes, then the cloning algorithm will ignore it and you'll start to see strange errors.

My recommendation is to run `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myDoc))` before you insert it into PouchDB. Either that, or don't use custom classes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll add a method toPlainObject() in my custom classes.

Answer (score 1):

in JS there is little difference between objects, and PouchDB inserts proprieties to manage the indexing [see here](https://pouchdb.com/guides/updating-deleting.html#why-must-we-dance-this-dance).

You could do this..

```
db.put({ mydoc: myDoc })
```

but it's really an issue?

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't really answer. I'd like to know precisely why I haven't this behavior with a native object. Okay I know PouchDb inserts properties but it shoudn't modify directly the object I put in parameter.